# Copy Site column lookup value to different column in Sub Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office

I have site column and a list using this site column in parent site. In sub site i created a list referencing this site column as lookup. I am able to select the lookup value but is there any way to copy text value to another column or variable?

Comment: Copy text? Can you explain in more detail what you need...

Comment: I want to use the lookup value in list workflow. As i cannot use the lookup value directly i wanted to copy the lookup value as text. Let me know if there is alternative